# About the proof of the theorem that assures that a surface is invariant with respect to a system of differential equations.

Tags: geometry, ordinary-differential-equations, mathematical-modeling

I have seen the next theorem in [A Lotka-Volterra three species food chain](http://people.kzoo.edu/barth/math280/articles/3speciesLV.pdf),

> Theorem 0.1: Let S be a smooth surface in $\mathbb{R}^3$ and
>   \begin{equation}
> \begin{cases}
> &\frac{dx}{dt}=f(x,y,z),\\
> &\frac{dy}{dt}=g(x,y,z),\\
> &\frac{dz}{dt}=h(x,y,z),
> \end{cases}
> \end{equation}
>   where $f$, $g$ and $h$ are continuously differentiable. Suppose that $\textbf{n}$
>    is a normal vector to the surface S at $(x,y,z)$, and for all $(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3$ we have that
>   \begin{equation*}
> \textbf{n}\cdot\left(\frac{dx}{dt},\frac{dy}{dt},\frac{dz}{dt}\right)=0.
> \end{equation*}
>   Then, S is invariant with respect to the above system.

In the above reference, I have seen that they refer to V. Arnold's book "Ordinary Differential Equations" to search for the proof of this theorem, but I couldn't find it. Does someone know where could I find its proof? I don't mind if it is in Arnold's book or in another place.

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Take any Calc III book and find a proof (or better prove it yourself) that if the surface is defined by the equation $u(x)=C$ then vector gradient $\nabla u(x)$ at the point $x$ is exactly the normal to this surface at this point.

Comment: Thank you very much, Artem. I remember the result you mention from Vector Calculus course; I didn't relate them to each other when I read the theorem I am asking about. I will try to think about it and see it in the way you mention.

Thank you again.